# Can we change sub totals by filtering category?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Category column where am showing grand total for Category.But now i want to filter total Category wise.Suppose if in front end i select 2 category then it should show that two categories total , if i select 3 then it should be 3 categories total.

If it is possible then please let me know.

```
Portfolio Product  Revenue
Total     NULL      600
First     P1        100
Second    P2        200
Third     P3        100
Fourth    P4        200
```

In front end if i will select First and Second Portfolio then Total value should come 300.Like that if i select any combination it show that level addition.

Comment: In SQL that corresponds to IN, like `WHERE Category IN ('category1', 'category2')`

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and your existing query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff   I did edition..please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Use SUM together with IN for filtering

```
SELECT SUM(revenue)
FROM someTable
WHERE portfolio IN ('First', 'Second')
```